Is there a way to get the logger name (e.g. module name in getLogger(__name__) ) when creating custom logging TimedRotatingFileHandler?
Im trying to create a custom TimedRotatingFileHandler. For loggers that should be in a single log file, I create custom file handlers like this, to automatically create directory for log files if it doesnt exist:
class CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, *args, **kwargs):
        log_path = os.path.dirname(filename) # filename passes full path, seperate path from filename
        pathlib.Path(log_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # Use the seperated path to create directories for logfile
        logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, log_name, *args, **kwargs)

What I wanted to do know was create a special handler, that would create a log file not from predefined name, but from the module name that I pass when creating a logger with logging.getLogger(name). Loggers with this handler would create their own log file with their own module name:
class CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, *args, **kwargs):
        log_path = os.path.dirname(filename) # filename passes full path, seperate path from filename
        pathlib.Path(log_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # Use the seperated path to create directories for logfile
        logger_name = # Somehow get the logger name e.g module name from __name__
        new_filename  f"{log_path}/{logger_name}.log" # create new filename for the __init__
        logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, new_filename, *args, **kwargs)

Currently, to achieve same functionality, I have to create seperate handler for each logger to have them be logged in seperate files.
So the question is: how do I get the logger name inside the Handler?

You can add whatever parameters you need to your custom handler's __init__ method, so why not just add a logger_name parameter, which you then set when calling logger.addHandler(CustomTimedRotatingLogHandler(filename, __name__))?
If you still want to try to get the __name__ of the calling module, you can get that with the inspect module as detailed here, but this is a fragile solution and breaks encapsulation. In general a function or method shouldn't know or care who the caller was.
As an additional change, I also updated the last line to call super().__init__() instead of directly referencing the parent class.
custom_logger.py
import inspect
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import pathlib


class CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, logger_name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if logger_name is None:
            logger_name = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.get("__name__", "<unknown>")
        log_path = os.path.dirname(filename) # filename passes full path, seperate path from filename
        pathlib.Path(log_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # Use the seperated path to create directories for logfile

        new_filename = f"{log_path}/{logger_name}.log" # create new filename for the __init__
        super().__init__(new_filename, *args, **kwargs)

my_module.py
import logging

from custom_logger import CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler

logger=logging.getLogger("")
# Use default logger_name in handler
logger.addHandler(custom.CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler("./logs/custom_log_from_module.log"))
logger.critical("Message from Module")

# Submit a logger_name to handler
second=logging.getLogger("SecondLogger")
second.addHandler(custom.CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler("./logs/custom_log_2_from_module.log", logger_name="Second_logger_Override"))
logger.debug("Message from Module")

main.py
import logging

import custom_logger
import my_module

logger = logging.getLogger()

def main():
    # Send override name to handler
    logger.addHandler(custom_logger.CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler("./logs/Log_From_Main.txt", logger_name="From_main"))
    logger.warning("Logging a message from main")
    
    # Have handler use default
    second_main = logging.getLogger("2ndMain")
    second_main.addHandler(custom_logger.CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler("./logs/FromMain2.log"))
    second_main.warning("Second message from main")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

And you can see the passed in logger_name value was used for the filename when available.  The default case in my_module.py used "my_module", while the default case from my __main__ script was unable to get the name from the framestack and used the fallback of "_unknown_" instead.

In my opinion, it would be better to just make logger_name a required parameter, instead of trying to pull info from the framestack.

I'll just a comment that with the setup above, the logged message "Second message from main" is logging to both _unknown_.log and From_main.log, so it must be considering that as a parent logger.   The others are only being logged to their respective files

I forgot to mention I only use dictConfig to configure the logging. dicConfig only allows to pass list of handler names. inspect.currentframe() would have worked for me, but it seems all the loggers are getting .

If you're using dictConfig, you can send additional keyword arguments to the handler by simply adding them as additional keys.  From the docs -- All other keys are passed through as keyword arguments to the handler’s constructor.  There is an example given passing filename, maxBytes and backupCount to RotatingFileHandler

So If I have a single RotatingFileHandler defined, how can I make it so that every logger that I give this handler, makes its own file from its name? What you suggested sounds like I need to create handler with its own filename/parameters for each logger, which is what I already do.

If you want the handler to create a different filenjame for each logger, then yes, there should be a separate instance of your handler created for each logger, and then pass a parameter to configure the filename (or just use the stem of the filename you're already passing in).
If you want more suggestions, consider posting a new question specifying that you are using dictConfig, with some examples of your current configuration and what your desired configuration would be for this scenario.
